# how to use files .ts in firebase with project react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase

This is the code I am using the ts files.

```js
import { firebaseConfig } from '../firebase'; // firebase.ts

 useEffect(() => {
    let unsubscribe = firebaseConfig
    .firestore() // it's error I don't know why
```

when import file firebaseConfig to file .ts happen error I don't know why

The error is in the following image.

[image]

Comment: If the answer helps you don't forget to mark it as accepted, otherwise keep asking questions in the comments

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't show pictures of text.  Copy the text into the question so that it's easier to read, copy, and search.

Comment: Also, you might want to edit the question to show all of the relevant code here, especially the contents of the file you're including.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are importing the wrong object.

```js
// firebase.ts

// this is what you are importing
var firebaseConfig = {
  // ...
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// this is what you should be importing
export default firebase;

// other-file.ts
import firebase from '../firebase'
```